Quelle est la différence de sens entre le conditionnel et l'imparfait ?
Dans le paragraphe suivant, quelle nuance de sens transmettent les formes du verbe "pouvoir", respectivement conjuguées au conditionnel et à l'imparfait ?
Pourrait-on justifier l’appellation "futur du passé" pour le conditionnel dans cet exemple ?
Dans la négative, quelle serait la différence entre "que nous allions pouvoir le faire" et "que nous pourrions le faire" ?
J'ai dit que cela m'était égal et que nous pourrions le faire si elle le voulait.
« Pourquoi m'épouser alors ? » a-t-elle dit. Je lui ai expliqué que cela n'avait aucune importance et que si elle le désirait, nous pouvions nous marier.
(Camus, L'Étranger)

Dans cet extrait de L'Étranger nous sommes en présence de phrases au discours indirect. Le passage du discours direct au discours indirect nécessite un changement de temps des verbes.
Présent de l'indicatif → Imparfait

Je lui ai expliqué : « Si tu veux nous pouvons nous marier. » → Je lui expliqué que si elle voulait nous pouvions nous marier.

Futur → Présent du conditionnel

Je lui ai dit : « Si tu veux nous pourrons nous marier. » →  Je lui ai dit que si elle voulait nous pourrions nous marier.

L'emploi du présent/imparfait rend l'action plus proche, plus probable.
L'emploi du futur/conditionnel fait prendre une distance de l'action, la rend donc moins effective.
On ne parle pas en général de futur du passé dans ce cas, mais on pourrait. On parle plutôt de futur du passé pour une phrase du genre :

Je me doutais que tu viendrais aujourd'hui.

Mais ce n'est que de la terminologie, l'essentiel c'est de comprendre le pourquoi.


Dans le paragraphe suivant, quelle nuance de sens transmettent les formes du verbe "pouvoir", respectivement conjuguées au conditionnel et à l'imparfait ?

La nuance de sens est appelée le deuxième conditionnel, irréel du présent (unlikely), quand l’imparfait est requis avec le conditionnel.  La formation if/then est parfois inversée then/if, et souvent le mot then n’est pas utilisé, comme dans l’exemple de texte.

Pourrait-on justifier l’appellation "futur du passé" pour le conditionnel dans cet exemple ?

Non.   Le sens irréel serait perdu, et il deviendrait le premier conditionnel, potentiel (likely), où le futur est utilisé avec le passé composé.

Dans la négative, quelle serait la différence entre "que nous allions pouvoir le faire" et "que nous pourrions le faire" ?

La première clause n’est pas fausse dans la négative, qu’il ne veut pas de mariage.  La seconde clause implique une insulte de qualité pourrie de mariage “avec” elle, ainsi pourquoi elle tristement dit « Pourquoi m'épouser alors ? ».
Et plus difficile d’expliquer …
…et que si elle le désirait, nous pouvions nous marier.
Le deuxième conditionnel si est encore utilisé, irréel du présent (unlikely),  mais il est intentionnellement erroné, et “avec” se marier sans avoir avec :
-Le pronominal se marier requiert avec, pourtant sans avec il implique qu’il ne veut pas de se marier “avec” elle.
-Le deuxième conditionnel si est en non-sens par l’imparfait et l’imparfait au lieu de l’imparfait et le conditionnel.   Eh quoi, c’est également irréel.

Hmmmmm, kézaco ?

@jlliagre
kézaco, c’est-à-dire “wassat”?   Selon WordReference, le mot est familier et humoristique, de l'argot.   Est-ce que mon explication est incorrecte ?   Il est certainement possible que je ne connaisse pas toute la grammaire particulière de l’histoire.

Disons que ta réponse est écrite dans un français difficile à appréhender, parfois même un peu surréaliste comme la phrase La seconde clause implique une insulte de qualité pourrie de mariage "avec" elle. Je ne sais pas quelle est ta langue maternelle mais est-ce que tu as utilisé un outil pour traduire ta réponse en français ?

Êtes-vous déroutés par ma phrase mal écrit en français ou êtes-vous offensés par mon interprétation du texte ?

L'interprétation va trop loin, à mon avis.

@GDiamond Le vocabulaire de la réponse est parfois offbeat. Il faut beaucoup réfléchir pour comprendre ce que tu veux dire. Je ne suis aucunement "offensé" par la phrase que j'ai citée (ou quoi que ce soit d'autre), je ne comprends simplement pas ce qu'elle signifie. Le dernier point est faux, il n'y a rien d'incorrect a omettre avec elle.

The second conditional if is in nonsense by the imperfect and the imperfect instead of the imperfect and the conditional. So what, that's also unreal. It took me a while to understand that.

Ouais, il m‘a aussi eu un certain temps pour comprendre la description du QLF pour le conditionnel si   https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/24140/la-grammaire/le-verbe/temps-grammaticaux/conditionnel/conditionnel-dans-les-phrases-hypothetiques

Paradoxically, there are many who believe that particular sentence of the text was written in error because the si conditional wasn’t constructed properly.   yes/no, it was in error, with the point being that he was purposely saying their marriage would be nonsense and in error, and that was very aggravating for her, especially after his implying that their marriage would be wasted or rotted (pourri).

@GDiamond Aie, si je ne comprends pas non plus où tu veux en venir quand tu t'exprimes en anglais, on n'est pas sortis de l'auberge...

"Many who believe ... written in error ": who does?// "*their marriage would be nonsense and in error": that is not how Meursault's words in this paragraph are usually  interpreted, so which of Meursault's words make you say the marriage would be "rotted" & it would be "aggravating" for Marie? Camus wants to show Meursault is indifferent, he has no feelings, but he's willing to comply to Marie's wishes.
